# C Program Crashes in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am getting this error whenever I run my code in visual Studio:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char username[10];
    printf("Enter Username: ");
    scanf_s("%[^\n]", &username);

    while (isupper(username)) {
        if (username == '-') {
            printf("Username cannot contain UpperCase Letters");
        }
    }
}
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTNJn.png)

Comment: You need to tell `scanf_s` the size of your buffer.

Comment: can you tell what this does->  '-'

Comment: why you used hyphen

Comment: Please put your error message in plain text in the question, it helps people that might have the same problem as you find your question

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can pass whole array to `isupper`. Also if you don't want to return anything instead of `int main()` use `void main()` or just return 0 in the end or when you want to end after your program executed successfully. As for using `scan_s` or `scanf` or `getline` or whatever I won't say anything because its a different matter and your syntax of `scanf_s` is certainly wrong.

Also following code will **not** check for any buffer overflow (not a good practice,  you will see even though we gave size 20 char array, this code will work even for larger input which is certainly not a good thing). So you can either limit the size of input or  better to read an entire line via `fgets()` (or `getline()` if available) and parse the string yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char username[20];
    printf("Enter Username: ");
    // scanf("%[^\n]", username); <--- Instead of this 
    scanf_s("%20c", username, 20); // <----Try Using this 
    int i=0;
    while (i<strlen(username)) {
        if (isupper(username[i])) {
            printf("Username cannot contain UpperCase Letters\n");
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still Facing the same problem with the code you provided. It says that "Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
"

Comment: @SaifUrRehmanChughtai I updated my answer scanf may sure be insecure, but if its just not running then that's a problem, I hope you have installed  GCC for C . If you just started learning , then you should not bother with this stuff, try running the code in online IDE and it will work fine without scanf_s, Just look for some video explaining how to run C codes in visual studio.

Comment: the problem was solved I just Added '#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS' at the first line and then there was no warning being displayed related to scanf_s. Thank You for the information. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that your while is an endless loop, try to do it like this:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<strlen(username);i++){
  if(isupper(username[i])){
    printf("Username cannot contain UpperCase Letters");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this fixes it, but definitely also account the Answer in the Comment of @user3386109.

Comment: Still getting the same error that Visual Studio has stopped working

Comment: You also tried to do what @user3386109 told you?